# Select "X" number of options using html, JS

Tags: javascript, html

How would you verify that someone would only check no more than 2 options? This is a very weird question to google search and could not find an article. I would prefer a JS method.

```
 <select multiple>
      <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
      <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
      <option value="sausage">Sausage</option>
      <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: You need to assign the values to a variable, and then check that variable for the length you want.  In this case, 2.

Answer (score 1):

You would look at the [`selectedOptions.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions) of the select the `click` event of the select and then not allow further selections when that count is greater than 2.

```js
$(function() {
  // Get references to the different select elements and convert
  // them into Arrays:
  var pizzaSelect =
    Array.prototype.slice.call(
      document.querySelectorAll("#pizzaOptions > option"));
  var sodaSelect =
    Array.prototype.slice.call(
      document.querySelectorAll("#soda > option"));
  
  // Loop over each list's options, executing the supplied 
  // callback function for each one.
  pizzaSelect.forEach(checkSelectionCount);
  sodaSelect.forEach(checkSelectionCount);
  
  function checkSelectionCount(opt, idx, ary){
    // Add a click event listener to each option:
    opt.addEventListener("click", function(event){
      // Is a 3rd option clicked and being selected?
      if(this.parentNode.selectedOptions.length === 3 && this.selected) { 
        this.selected = false; // De-select it.
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="pizzaOptions">
      <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
      <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
      <option value="sausage">Sausage</option>
      <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    </select>
<br><br>
<select multiple id="soda">
      <option value="coke">Coke</option>
      <option value="sprite">Sprite</option>
      <option value="dr_pepper">Dr. Pepper</option>
</select>
```

Comment: ok thanks for help. would plus one but cant yet. will experiment with your solution.

Comment: how would you `let options = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("option")); `  if you had multiple <select></selects>  option lists. For example, if you had a pizza, soda, and breadsticks options as well. Assuming you would do getElementById(#pizzaOptions)

Comment: @chessmaster1 You would just modify the selector passed to `.querySelectorAll()` as in `document.querySelectorAll("#pizzaOptions > option")` to get all the `option` elements that are children within the `select` with an `id = pizzaOptions`.

Comment: I created a codepen dont think its 100% working: https://codepen.io/ScottFSchmidt/pen/QzGWGP?editors=1010   . I should probably use a checklist option too now that I think about it. someone would not be able to select options this method at top and then bottom.

Comment: @chessmaster1 You didn't duplicate the code that I showed in your CodePen. I've corrected the Pen as well as modifying the answer here to show how to do this will multiple lists.